# Get shortest xpath to element in Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, xpath

This is the base script I'm trying to change

http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/hsv97/2/

It gives the xpath to the clicked element.
When you click `with deeper`  it returns

```
//html/body/div[2]/em#emphatic/span#deepest.red
```

That's the complete path to the element. But if the webmaster decides to put in an extra `div`, then the path to `#deepest.red` gets broken. 
What i want is the shortest possible path, calculated from the nearest `id` . So in this case,  I only need  `#deepest.red` which i later can use to address this element again with

`$x("//div[contains(@id,'deepest-red')]");`

Can someone point me in the right direction to change this fiddle to fit my needs.......

Comment: Why `//div[contains(@id,'deepest-red')]`? Shouldn't it be `//div[@id='deepest-red']`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understood your request, but if you need to solve the problem of an extra `<div>` in the path, then the 'descendant-or-self' axis.

> descendant-or-self
>   Selects all descendants (children, grandchildren, etc.) of the current node and the current node itself

So your XPath will look like below:

```
//html/body/descendant-or-self::div/em#emphatic/span#deepest.red
```